# inside facebook app when clicked on link refreshes page and shows blank page

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook app which has 4 pages. When i try to click on the link it just refreshes the page and shows a blank page. If i click on the link and open in a new tab it works fine opens the other page properly. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to just add target="_top" in the anchor tag to solve the blank page issue.